# SQLite in Android not updating or deleting content

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am developing an app which uses SQLite. So far there has been no problem, I have been able to insert rows and everything, but when it comes to update or delete the data is not changed.

I didn't use the `beginTransaction()` and `endTransaction()` at the beginning because the insert statement did its job and didn't need it, but researching & trying to find the solution I left that there, which I assume is like making a commit.

Perhaps the problem is that I don't use an ID in the WHERE clause, I use a latitude and a longitude (which are pretty unique too and makes things easier for me), but I don't know, I should be able to use whatever condition I like in the WHERE clause.

The next piece of code is inside my SQLite handler/helper

```
public void updateMarker(String title, String description, double latitude, double longitude, String color){
          ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
          valores.put("title",title);
          valores.put("description",description);
          valores.put("lat",latitude);
          valores.put("long",longitude);
          valores.put("color",color);

          this.getWritableDatabase().beginTransaction();
          // Not updating (deleting is pretty much the same code)
          this.getWritableDatabase().update("markers", valores, "lat='"+latitude+"' AND long='"+longitude+"';", null);

          this.getWritableDatabase().setTransactionSuccessful();
          this.getWritableDatabase().endTransaction();
          this.getWritableDatabase().close();
      }
```

This method is called like this; addMarker is a Marker, and color is a string. I am sure that there are no null pointers.

```
handler.updateMarker(addMarker.getTitle(), addMarker.getSnippet(), addMarker.getPosition().latitude, addMarker.getPosition().longitude, color);
```

The expected results are that when I load the markers, it should load the updated ones with the new info, and don't load the deleted ones, but it just doesnt.

**SOLUTION:** What I did was create a new class with an object marker and a int ID, now everything works perfectly.

Comment: 1) Can you give some sample data, an example call to this method, the actual results, and the expected result? 2) Where do the values for `latitude` and `longitude` come from? If they come from the user, your code is susceptible to SQL Injection. You should use a parameterized query instead of building the query with string concatenations.

Comment: 3) The transaction shouldn't be necessary because you are only performing a single query. Transactions are usually meant for batching multiple queries for efficiency. 4) To answer your question directly, the most likely problem is that you are comparing floating point values for equality. This is a big no no.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice 1) Done. 2) Come from the app, but thankyou for the advice. I know I should use a parametirzed query, will do it next time. I cant be this lazy. 3) Thankyou! I didnt know that 4) That looks like the issue, I'll look into it. Any ide on how to aproach it?

Comment: What do you mean "from the app"? Does the user input it or do you use Location Services?

Comment: 1) Can you give a more concrete example? Specifically, provide example data in the table, specific numbers that are passed to the method, and the expected change to the table.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yeah, sorry I didnt make it clear, the user performs a long click on a map and it retrieves de latitude and longitude, there are no input forms

Comment: Since you are getting the lat and long from the device hardware, you are probably less susceptible unless someone finds a way to spoof or hack said hardware.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The data is irrelevant, as the delete statement fails to work too, so i'd say the issue lies in the where. I tried to make the field TEXT, and parse the doubles to strings, but its still not working

Comment: Yes, I went a little overboard on my suggestions. IMO, the data is completely relevant to asking a question because it can make our conversation much more concrete. Also, parsing the doubles as strings still doesn't necessarily resolve round off and representation issues when comparing for equality.

Comment: Concrete data is absolutely necessary to debug the issue. One thought is to double check the database to see if the content is udpated/deleted? This will help you narrow down the problem between updating/deleting or requerying.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The data is still there and untouched, because the map loads the markers as they were added, in their correct positions and everything. Im thinking Im going to have to make a class that extends Marker and add an ID attribute to keep track of each marker

Comment: or you could add the id attribute directly to `Marker`.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing floating point values for equality. This is most likely the cause of your problems. I'm not sure of a soution right now.

As for some other suggestions:

1. The transaction is unnecessary since you are only performing a single query.  Transactions are usually meant for batching multiple queries for efficiency.
2. Your code is susceptible to SQL Injection because of the String concatenations. You should instead use a parameterized WHERE clause:

   ```
   String where = "lat=? AND long=?"
   String[] whereArgs = {Double.toString(latitude), Double.toString(longitude)};
   this.getWritableDatabase().update("markers", valores, where, whereArgs);
   ```
3. You can save some overhead by calling `getWriteableDatabase()` once and assinging the DB object to a reference.
4. You can reduce the number of parameters for your method by passing `addMarker` in directly and calling the getters to create the `ContentValues` object.

   1. I find it convenient to create a `getContentValues()` method which takes a model object (`Marker` in your case, perhaps?) and returns a `ContentValues`. This neatly encapsulates the conversion for use throughout the app.